# Push values of clicked elements in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to send with ajax the values of the clicked buttons to my php file. I.e. The user click `btn1`, then the value `1` should pushed into the array and ajax should send it to my file `screen.php`.

My console shows now `Yay it worked`

**my js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var ajaxurl = 'screen.php';
    $values = [];
    $('.ui-btn').click(function(){
    $values.push($(this).val());
});
$.ajax({
       url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            buttons: $values,
        },
        success: function (result) {
           console.log('Yay it worked' + $values);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

**my html:**

```
 <div>
    <button name="btn1" type="submit" id="btn1" value="1" class="ui-btn"></button>
    <button name="btn2" type="submit" id="btn2" value="2" class="ui-btn"></button>
    </div> // I have up to 9 buttons, thats only a piece
```

Comment: `$values` is not available in the scope?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your `.ajax` seems to be called before the clicks, even earlier than domready.

Comment: the value attribute on the button tag??

And probably... wehn you perform the ajax request the $values array is empty because nobody clicked them yet!!

Comment: At which point you want to fire an ajax call? Is there another button on which you want to perform that?

Comment: Yeah this is not really clear... And you have to better indent your code, it's not helping like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some modifications to your code to hopefully achieve what you want.  This will save an array of values and POST it to your php script every time a button is clicked.  I've removed some unused variables and cleaned up the indentation.  I can't say if it will work on the receiving end, because I cannot see the php file.

```
var values = [];

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.ui-btn').click(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            url: 'screen.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                buttons: values,
            },
            success: function() {
               console.log('Yay it worked', values);
            },
            error: function() {
               console.log('Something went wrong');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ajax to be called each time the button is clicked, then you need to place it in the callback for the event handler of the button. Right now, your code calls ajax once when the document is ready. It is using the empty array first set when the document is ready before any buttons are clicked. Place the ajax call inside the click callback and it should call ajax with the updated array each time.